# HL1, TF1, CS 1.6 crashes down

Tags: windbg

I have in their steam folders *.mdmp files. I opened them in WinDbg and got this output:

```
Microsoft (R) Windows Debugger Version 6.2.8400.0 AMD64
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.


Loading Dump File [C:\Users\Guy Fawkes\Downloads\half-life\hl_4554_crash_2012_6_20T14_42_49C0.mdmp]
Comment: 'hl: valve
'
User Mini Dump File: Only registers, stack and portions of memory are available

Symbol search path is: *** Invalid ***
****************************************************************************
* Symbol loading may be unreliable without a symbol search path.           *
* Use .symfix to have the debugger choose a symbol path.                   *
* After setting your symbol path, use .reload to refresh symbol locations. *
****************************************************************************
Executable search path is: 
Windows 7 Version 7601 (Service Pack 1) MP (2 procs) Free x86 compatible
Product: WinNt, suite: SingleUserTS
Machine Name:
Debug session time: Wed Jun 20 18:42:49.000 2012 (UTC + 4:00)
System Uptime: not available
Process Uptime: 0 days 0:00:02.000
................................................................
............
This dump file has an exception of interest stored in it.
The stored exception information can be accessed via .ecxr.
(16a8.16e8): Access violation - code c0000005 (first/second chance not available)
*** WARNING: Unable to verify timestamp for ntdll.dll
*** ERROR: Module load completed but symbols could not be loaded for ntdll.dll
eax=0cb50f98 ebx=00000000 ecx=0000039c edx=0cb50fa0 esi=302942e1 edi=00000398
eip=76e67094 esp=0012c134 ebp=0012c144 iopl=0         nv up ei pl zr na pe nc
cs=001b  ss=0023  ds=0023  es=0023  fs=003b  gs=0000             efl=00200246
ntdll+0x47094:
76e67094 c3              ret
```

Game started, menu with Gordon Freeman picture showed, and window closing itself.

Comment: I have some problem. Up.

Comment: This output ia almost meaningless. After opening WinDbg, can you please do the following: `.symfix c:\symbols` and then `.exr -1` and `kb`. Then we might come closer to a solution.